# «Убивая спасает». Заголовок к статье. можно ли поменять местами слова? Верно ли без запятой?

Tags: деепричастия

«Убивая спасает». Заголовок к статье. можно ли поменять местами слова – Спасает убивая (так кажется, было бы лучше. Речь о антибиотиках. 
Верно ли без запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Убивая спасАет**

Я бы оставила заголовок без изменения.

Здесь деепричастие в роли обстоятельства, паузу делать нежелательно, логическое ударение не на обоих словах (как при постановке запятой), а только на втором. Да и в заголовках лишние запятые нежелательны.

При перестановке (спасает убивАя) ударение падает на деепричастие, а по смыслу важен именно глагол.

Comment: У Вас ударение падает на глагол и подчеркивает, что нам важно то, что антибиотик спасАет, — но получается, что он пришел убивать — и вдруг спас, УРА! А мне кажется, нам важно обратить внимание читателя именно то, что антибиотик убивает. Его главное действое — спасать, а он, оказывается, убивАет: "СпасАя, убивАет".

Answer (score 2):

Заголовок в данном случае формулирует идею текста, поэтому очень важно правильно выразиться, расставив нужные акценты с помощью выбора позиции деепричастия и с помощью  знаков препинания.

Запятая нужна, так как деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие, сохраняя оттенок глагольности, ср.:*спасает и убивает*.

***Убивая, спасает.*** - Подходит, если антибиотик убивает микробов, а не иммунитет, при этом спасая человека.

***Спасая, убивает.*** - Подходит, если убивает иммунитет, но человека таки спасает.

***Спасая...убивает?*** - Подходит, если в статье заявлена и заострена  проблема вреда антибиотиков, если необходимо сделать выбор. (Здесь запятая поглощается многоточием.)

Comment: "Спасая, убивает" мне даже больше нравится, чем "Спасает, убивая".

Comment: В первую очередь антибиотик спасает, а не убивает...Ведь так?

Answer (score 1):

Антибиотик спасает нас и убивает одновременно. Он спасает — это главное его действие. Поэтому лучше сказать "**Спасает, убивая**". Два действия незвисимы, поэтому я считаю, что деепричастие должно отделяться.

"Спасает убивая" без запятой означает спасение путем убийства (спасает людей убивая микробы).

Comment: ведь второе верно, без запятой....спасает людей убивая микробы!

Comment: Но мы-то имеем в виду, что спасает нас от воспаления, убивая нашу иммунную систему, микробов мы как-то не жалеем...

Comment: Но ведь нет зависимого слова рядом с «убивая»...Или же деепричастие обозначает второе действие? И спасает, и убивает?

Comment: Именно так. Антибиотик спасает нас и убивает одновременно. Деепричастие обозначает  второе действие.